# Preventing redirect to router/proxy (firefox, keyword.url)

Tags: firefox, proxy, address-bar, about-config, keyword

I keep getting redirected to my router page (at home) and a squid proxy server here when entering, e.g. "superuser" in the Address Bar.

How do I make Firefox conform to its [Keyword.URL](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyword.URL); which I've set to Google's "Browse by name"?

Comment: Is your DNS provider redirecting incorrect URLs to their own search provider?

Comment: Yeah (at home); where I was before they just direct me to a proxy error "Page not found".